Hi fellow developers, there is something I need to know about DataSync Start ExecutionApi
I am working with Data sync start execution Api.
I have One stack in which I am creating all the locations, Tasks, Role and I am using DataSync client with startExecutionApi to call the task in the same stack.
My code Snippet for dataSync looks something like this
const client = new DataSyncClient();
const input = {
  TaskArn: TASK1.attrTaskArn,
};
const command = new StartTaskExecutionCommand(input);
(async () => {
  const response = await client.send(command);
})(); 

But I am getting below Error

const exception = new InvalidRequestException({
^
InvalidRequestException: Invalid parameter: Malformed ARN: ${Token[TOKEN.110]}.
at de_InvalidRequestExceptionRes (/codebuild/output/src4271555059/src/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-datasync/dist-cjs/index.js:1945:21)
at de_CommandError (/codebuild/output/src4271555059/src/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-datasync/dist-cjs/index.js:1923:19)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async /codebuild/output/src4271555059/src/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/index.js:35:20
at async /codebuild/output/src4271555059/src/node_modules/@smithy/core/dist-cjs/index.js:165:18
at async /codebuild/output/src4271555059/src/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/index.js:320:38
at async /codebuild/output/src4271555059/src/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-logger/dist-cjs/index.js:33:22
at async /codebuild/output/src4271555059/src/lib/stacks/be-customer-migration-stack.ts:65:28 {
'$fault': 'client',
'$metadata': {
httpStatusCode: 400,
requestId: 'b124d220-8350-4bc5-9cb1-219211c65fea',
extendedRequestId: undefined,
cfId: undefined,
attempts: 1,
totalRetryDelay: 0
},
errorCode: 'InvalidParameter',
datasyncErrorCode: undefined,
__type: 'InvalidRequestException'
}

I tried few things and I observed
If I hard code TASK1.attrTaskArn with the task arn, that has been already created and then print the response. I get 200 Ok; the task also gets triggered during the synth stage of my pipeline.
(Info:-> I use pipeline to deploy the stack, and not directly deploy it)
From what I have found through some research is that, datasync client is not able to resolve the arn token at the time of deployment.
Is it because both task creation and execution are being done at the same time?
Is there any way to do both of them in same stack?

This looks like a good question overall AFAICT (yay!) but with haphazard punctuation/capitalization and poor indentation in the code block, it is a bit jarring to look at. You might get more immediate feedback if you correct these simple formatting issues.

Thanks for the suggestion, I tried formatting it. Hope the Question is more understandable now

Looks good! I didn't want to sound overly nitpicky, but presentation makes a surprisingly huge difference (and thus a lot easier) for people to digest a problem. Also my thanks to you, as I wasn't aware of the aws repost site.

I found my answer in aws repost
It was because I am making an AWS SDK call in your CDK application code.
Need to change it to either custom resource or add additional steps to my pipeline.
I Will post the code snippet Once I am done with it.
https://repost.aws/questions/QUjGdb9lxbTeSuMKcMUMyWPg/datasync-start-execution-api
EDIT:-> I created a custom function to invoke the task every time I deploy the stack


 const uniqueId = Date.now().toString();
    new cr.AwsCustomResource(this, `${uniqueId}-CustomResource1`, {
      onCreate: {
        service: 'DataSync',
        action: 'startTaskExecution',
        parameters: {
          TaskArn: taskArn,
        },
        physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(`CustomResource1-${Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)}`),
      },
      onUpdate: {
        service: 'DataSync',
        action: 'startTaskExecution',
        parameters: {
          TaskArn: taskArn,
        },
        physicalResourceId: cr.PhysicalResourceId.of(`CustomResource1-${Math.random().toString(36).substring(2, 15)}`),
      },
      policy: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.fromSdkCalls({ resources: cr.AwsCustomResourcePolicy.ANY_RESOURCE }),
      role: customResourceRole,
    });



